# Disable HSTS for nginx-ingress using ConfigMap

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I've tried other related solutions but I can't seem to get this working right and I'm sure it is just a namespacing issue or something because this is my first experience with using ConfigMaps, but can someone help me troubleshoot why this isn't working?

Here's my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: brushfire-ingress
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: brushfire-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: brushfire
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: brushfire
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: brushfire-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "brushfire.online"
        - "*.brushfire.online"
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: "brushfire.online"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: brushfire
              servicePort: 80
    - host: "*.brushfire.online"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: brushfire
              servicePort: 80
```

And this is installed as part of a helm chart that is installed with `--namespace jorin-ssl`

The ConfigMap I tried is:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: brushfire-ingress
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx # I've also tried `jorin-ssl`
data:
  hsts: "false"
```

But in the end, the HSTS always appears to be there:

```
$ curl -s -D- https://brushfire.online/ | grep -i Strict
```

returns

```
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
```

For simplicity, I'd love to do this without using a ConfigMap at all. Is there not a way to do this with the annotations like we do with `force-ssl-redirect` etc?

Comment: Is that the right name for the configmap? You should see the name in your ingress deployment as the `--configmap` option. The value defaults to the [full name of the controller in helm](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#L89). Did you delete all existing pods after the change?

Comment: @Matt that looks like that worked! I guess I didn't understand how the configmap connected to the ingress. Its actually in the controller?

Comment: The nginx-ingress controller process talks directly to the kubernetes API to lookup data, like you running `kubectl get cm blah` it needs a name top lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/) must match what the nginx-ingress controller process is looking up.

The nginx-ingress process will use the `--configmap` argument on the command line to set the name. This option will be available in the container spec included in your deployment yaml.

For example, the helm deployment uses the [full name of the controller](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#L89) for the `--configmap` option.